# HTTP/1.1 407 error with latest Apache HttpClient 4.1.1 when using NTLM authentication

Tags: java, proxy, ntlm, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to use the Apache HttpClient 4.1.1 library (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html) to access sites from behind my company's proxy that uses the ISA Server with NTLM authentication but I keep getting an HTTP 407 Proxy Authentication Required error:

**Code Snippet**

```java
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("myProxyHost", 80, "http");
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);

    NTCredentials creds = new NTCredentials("myWindowsUserName", "myWindowsPwd", "localhost", "myCompanyDomain");
    AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope("myProxyHost", 80, "", "NTLM");
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(authScope, creds);

    HttpHost target = new HttpHost("www.google.com", 80, "http");
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("/");
    System.out.println("executing request to " + target + " via " + proxy);
    HttpResponse rsp = httpClient.execute(target, get);

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(rsp.getStatusLine());
    Header[] headers = rsp.getAllHeaders();
    for (int i = 0; i<headers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(headers[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
```

**O/P**

```
executing request to http://www.google.com:80 via http://myProxyHost:80
----------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )
Via: 1.1 myCompanyServer
Proxy-Authenticate: Negotiate
Proxy-Authenticate: Kerberos
Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 4120  
----------------------------------------
```

What am I missing here?

Update:
In the same environment, code using the JDK URL and URLConnection classes works!

**Working Code Snippet**

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "myProxyHost");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");

    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
```

**O/P**

```
Google window.google={kEI:"_N3cTaLFMY6cvgOH9MypDw",...
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with HttpClient 4.1.2.   For me, it was resolved by reverting to HttpClient 4.0.3.   I could never get NTLM working with 4.1.2 using either the built-in implementation or using JCIFS.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no issues with LGPL licensed software you can try using NTLM engine developed by the [Samba JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) project instead of the internal one used by Apache HttpClient per default.

See this document for detailed instructions:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/src/site/apt/ntlm.apt

PS: JDK URL and URLConnection classes work because they make use of platform specific calls when running on Microsoft Windows

Comment: (http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html) says it's no longer supported. I was anyways hoping HttpClient would suffice as its documentation claims full NTLM support now. That's the reason I was thinking there's something wrong with my code.

Comment: Jespa, the alternative mentioned on the jCIFS site looks interesting.

Comment: @kodeninja This is a common misunderstanding about JCIFS. What is deprecated is their HTTP related code, not the library itself